# How to properly disable form field in UCI using javascript

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-online, xrm

I am trying to disable a date field(by selecting date) in the Dynamics365 CRM UCI version. It is disabling it but on selecting the date twice. It is working fine in a classical mode but not on UCI

here is my code.

```
function ConfirmFunction(){
    debugger;
    var get_aob_date = Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("ies_aobdatercvd");
    var confirmStrings = { text:"This is a confirmation.", title:"Confirmation Dialog" };
    var confirmOptions = { height: 200, width: 450 };
    Xrm.Navigation.openConfirmDialog(confirmStrings, confirmOptions).then(
function (success) {    
    if (success.confirmed)
         get_aob_date.setDisabled(true);
    else
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ies_aobdatercvd").setValue();
});

}
```

Comment: probably the layout is not refreshed, since you are doing it inside promise (success callback). wild guess though

Answer (score 2):

Is this in a custom web resource?

The use of Xrm.Page is deprecated for everything other than custom web resources(currently) and should be replaced with the execution context.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/important-changes-coming#some-client-apis-are-deprecated

Here is what your code should look like to disable your field:

```
function DisableDate(executionContext){

var formcontext = executionContext.getFormContext();
formcontext.getControl("ies_aobdatercvd").setDisabled(true);
}
```

When you add the event to the onLoad (or any other event) you'll need to check the "Pass execution context" checkbox:

[image: Event Handler Properties]

Comment: What is not working?  When you add the function and attach it to the onLoad event, what happens when you load the form?  Is there any error?  Is there anything in the console?